# Create a view which is a vector created from different columns?

Tags: arrays, julia

For matrices `A`, `B`, and `C`, and some integer `i`, is there an easy way to make view whose result is

```
vec([A[:,i];B[:,i];C[:,i]])
```

without creating any temporaries? My current try is:

```
A = rand(4,4); B = rand(4,4); C = rand(4,4)
[@view(A[:,1]);@view(B[:,1]);@view(C[:,1])]
```

that obviously creates the vector at the end instead of a view to the four columns stacked as a vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for a lazy version of `cat`. Here's one implementation:

[lazy cat http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/Lazy-Cat.jpg](http://www.mrwallpaper.com/wallpapers/Lazy-Cat.jpg)

But in all seriousness, consider the (still experimental) solution ahwillia has here: [CatViews.jl](https://github.com/ahwillia/CatViews.jl). In your situation, `CatView(@view(A[:,1]), @view(B[:,1]), @view(C[:,1]))` would work.